# What is the Pythonic way to make sure a certain type or argument is passed correctly into a function/class?

Tags: python

If I want to make sure certain variables are certain types of data in the function input arguments, how am I supposed to check it "Pythonically"?

For example, is this the way you're supposed to do it?

```
def test1(int1):
    if type(int1) == int:
        int1 = int1 + 4
    else:
        raise(RuntimeError)
    return int1
```

I'm sure someone has asked this question before but I honestly don't know what to search for.

Also addendum question: How do function annotations play into all of this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance

Answer (score 3):

I would not check type of the parameter. Python will raise error only if it cannot handle addition between the object you passed and int object `4`:

```
>>> def test1(int1):
...     return int1 + 4
...
>>> test1(1)
5
>>> test1(1.5)
5.5
>>> test1('a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in test1
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

If you want to raise different error, catch `TypeError`:

```
def test1(int1):
    try:
        return int1 + 4
    except TypeError:
        raise RuntimeError
```

Comment: What exactly is the "standard" way most people let their users know how to document the function? Do you, say personally, write the argument type in the function's docstring? Do you use annotations? How do you convey to your users (and your future self) what the correct type the arguments should be?

Comment: @johnzilla, If you use Python 3.x, you can use [Function Annotation](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/). Otherwise, docstring.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Python folks like to say it's easier to ask forgiveness than ask permission (EAFP). Maybe something like:

```
def test1(int1):
  try:
    int1 = int1 + 4
  except TypeError:
    raise RuntimeError
  return int1
```

Just try it, and catch the error if it fails.

Comment: But if all you are doing is re-raising the error, then don't do try-except at all; Python is already raising an error for you.  If you want to do something non-functional when the exception occurs, like logging, do that in a decorator - leave the function's implementation as clean as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to check the arg type a pythonic way it to use [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance).

```
def test1(int1):
    if is instance(int1, int):
        int1 = int1 + 4
    else:
        raise(RuntimeError)
```

But, as @falsetru, would not like to check type too. Python already does it very well.

Also, I would use `try`and `exception` to change the flow, not to rise an error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is correct or not. But did you try like this:-

```
def test1(int1):
   try:
        int1 = int1 + 4
    except:
        raise(RuntimeError)

    return int1
```